# Tablix percentage calculation by column using row group aggregates - how to reference aggregates

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

Am trying to calculate the percentage of a row group value against the row group column total and I don't seem to be able to reference the right cells.

I have five nested row groups:

> ```
> country
>  -region
>   -county
>    -borough
>     -local authority
> ```

and one column group, which is fiscal year. I am counting the distinct cases and distinct enquiries by fiscal year and by country, which expands to region, which expands to county ... and so on.

*My basic expression is this:*

```
=FormatPercent(Countdistinct(Fields!CaseID.Value, "Local_Authorities")/CountDistinct(Fields!CaseID.Value, "FiscalYear_Text"))
```

this gives me a percentage which I can work out how it comes to be, so I am guessing my referencing is none-sensical

*when I use:*

```
=FormatPercent(Countdistinct(Fields!CaseID.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!CaseID.Value, "FiscalYear_Text"))
```

the percentages are calcutated fine, but always against the colum total, ie all distinct cases by year, wheras I want the percentage of distinct cases by year within say a region, which itself is only a percentage of a country.

I hope I am being clear and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!